# updating Rails 2 routes to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I try to update the routes of my redmine's plugin gitosis. They work for Rails<3.1 but I work with Rails 3.5. I don't manage to find a solution to my problem.. Any help?

Old version :

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
    map.resources :public_keys, :controller => 'gitosis_public_keys', :path_prefix => 'my'
end
```

After some researches, I tried this :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    scope "my" do
        resources :public_keys do
            controller 'gitosis_public_keys' do
            end
        end
    end
end
```

but no success...

Answer (score 0):

i did not totally understand what the problem is, but i will try to point you to the right documentation anyways.

just a side note `I work with Rails 3.5` probably is a typo, isn't it?

read about how to configure your routes in the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use

i assume that you want to do something like `resources :public_keys, controller: 'gitosis_public_keys'`

Comment: To be honest, i don't really understand how to manipulate routes with rails (3.2, sorry for the typo).
But when I start my server with webrick with the 'old version' i have this error :
    "An error occured while loading the routes definition of redmine_gitosis plugin (/opt/redmine-2.3.2/plugins/redmine_gitosis/config/routes.rb): You are using the old router DSL which has been removed in Rails 3.1"

Comment: maybe some real life example helps understanding this: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/config/routes.rb